# Alert message for reaching a limit during navigation in excel userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am using following code to populate userform from tabulated data in excel sheet and trying to use a next and previous button to cycle through previous entries in a table and have done successfully. With this code, the previous button selects the previous row and load it into the userform. The next button selects the next row and load it into the userform as well.

**Question**: I want to limit cycling to the table only (from rows 339 to 390 in worksheet). I want to fix this code to limit navigation to the table and show alert message regarding first record and last record reached. I have fixed and tested code for "next" button successfully but code for previous button is not working.

Sharing whole code for your review and suggestions that will be highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdGetNext_Click()

Range("B339").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastRow = ActiveCell.Row
currentrow = currentrow + 1
If currentrow = lastRow + 1 Then
    currentrow = lastRow
    MsgBox "You have reached the last entered data!"
End If

txtmeas.Text = Cells(currentrow, 2).Value
txtsource.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4).Value
cmbmatric.Text = Cells(currentrow, 6).Value

End Sub

Private Sub cmdPreviousData_Click()

currentrow = currentrow - 1
If currentrow > 1 Then
    txtmeas.Text = Cells(currentrow, 2).Value
    txtsource.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4).Value
    cmbmatric.Text = Cells(currentrow, 6).Value
ElseIf currentrow = 1 Then
    MsgBox "This is your first record!"
    currentrow = currentrow + 1
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tested the code in my answer below ? any feedback ?

Comment: Hi Shai, Yes I tried but it didn't solve the issue. The codes I shared here is completely functional and working and the only issue is that it doesn't stop on rom number one of my table but keep moving to the previous rows. But for the next data button, it is working perfectly fine and showing message. So the only thing is to limit it to the first row.  To make it more clear, I have multiple tables on different rows and applying same code in each table. If you try this code on a table starting from Row 1 (A1), this is perfect for both directions (previous and next) but not for rest of tables.

Comment: I appreciate your time and assistance Shai Rado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a constant at the module level, representing the first row of the table you want to set: `Const TblFirstRow`.

Then, below, instead of `Range("B339")` you can use `Range("B" & TblFirstRow)` which will be more dynamic to modify in the future.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

' define a variable at the module level, for first row of the table
Const TblFirstRow   As Long = 339

Private Sub cmdGetNext_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, CurrentRow As Long

' get last row (not skipping blank cells)
LastRow = Range("B" & TblFirstRow).End(xlDown).Row

If CurrentRow + 1 > LastRow Then
    CurrentRow = LastRow
    MsgBox "You have reached the last entered data!"
Else
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
End If

txtmeas.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value
txtsource.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Value
cmbmatric.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 6).Value

End Sub

'================================================================

Private Sub cmdPreviousData_Click()

If CurrentRow - 1 < TblFirstRow Then
    CurrentRow = TblFirstRow
    MsgBox "This is your first record!"
Else
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow - 1
End If

txtmeas.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value
txtsource.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Value
cmbmatric.Text = Cells(CurrentRow, 6).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change "elseif currentrow = 1 then" to "else".

If you start where currentrow = 1 and run the cmdPreviousData_Click(), then you decrease the value of currentrow from 1 to 0 in the first line (currentrow = currentrow - 1). Then your if statement isn't ran because 0 is not >1 and your elseif is not ran either because 0 <>1.

Comment: Hi Charles, I tried but it didn't work. Please see my comment for Shai Rado solution where I explained my question in more detail. Thanks for your assistance!